# Can a master table have a relation to another master table?

Tags: mysql, database, join, database-design

I want to ask about my project that I am working on.

I have two tables, `ms_corporates` and `ms_subsidiaries`, and the term is one corporate can have many subsidiaries but one subsidiary can have only one corporate.

This is my table right now:

```
ms_corporates
-------------
corporate_id PK
corporate_name
corporate_address
corporate_phone

ms_subsidiaries
---------------
subsidiary_id PK
corporate_name FK
subsidiary_name
subsidiary_address
subsidiary_phone
```

Can I go make a relation between them  or do I have to make a table between them?

Comment: This is a candidate for a recursive relationship.  You don't need two tables in this case as both tables essentially have the same columns.  You simply need to create a "parent_corporate_id" with a foreign key defined as ms_corporates.corporate_id => ms_corporates.parent_corporate_id.  This is self-referential to the same table.  By definition, if there is a value in "parent_corporate_id", it is a subsidiary.This only holds true if a subsidiary can NEVER have more than one parent.

Comment: All you need to do to make it work is remove the "corporate_" to something more generic.  And your current FK won't work  because "corporate_name" is not the primary key in ms_corporates.  You can't create a FK on any column, it must be the primary from the "contributing" table, in this case ms_corporates.corporate_id.

Comment: @TGray You should post your comments as an answer. +1 especially for _"You don't need two tables in this case as both tables essentially have the same columns."_

Comment: You can't enforce that a corporate is not a subsidiary if you use a single, polymorphic table (without adding a surrogate identifier).

Answer (score 0):

Smells like a 1:many relationship.  Such is implemented by having `corporate_id` (not name) in the subsidiary table.  And index that column.

Then you can `JOIN` the tables to find information about the corporation that owns a subsidiary or find all the subsidiaries of a given corporation.

There is something else to consider.  A "corporation" and a "subsidiary" are really the same type of entity, aren't they?  Even your schema indicates that; see how the columns are virtually the same?  So...  You *probably* should have only one table, and put both in it.  It will have an `id` (a la `corporate_id` and `subsidiary_id`) and a `parent_id`.

`parent_id` is a link to the `id` of another row in the same table.  It is the link from the subsidiary to the corporation.  If it is `0`, then you are looking at a corporation.  Non-`0` means a subsidiary.

Search this forum for `parent_id`; you will probably find lots of other examples doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a candidate for a recursive relationship. You don't need two tables in this case as both tables essentially have the same columns. You simply need to create a "parent_corporate_id" with a foreign key defined as ms_corporates.corporate_id => ms_corporates.parent_corporate_id. This is self-referential to the same table. By definition, if there is a value in "parent_corporate_id", it is a subsidiary.This only holds true if a subsidiary can NEVER have more than one parent. All you need to do to make it work is remove the "corporate_" to something more generic. And your current FK won't work because "corporate_name" is not the primary key in ms_corporates. You can't create a FK on any column, it must be the primary from the "contributing" table, in this case ms_corporates.corporate_id.